# Exibir ProgressBar ao efetuar login no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Ao efetuar o login, eu quero que apareça uma barra de carregamento enquanto o login está sendo feito. Como faço para conseguir pegar o processo (tempo, tamanho...) do Firebase para poder incrementar na barra de progresso?

Segue o código do login:

```
private void efetuarLogin() {
    final FirebaseAuth autenticacaoFirebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAuth();
    autenticacaoFirebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            usuario.getEmail(),
            usuario.getSenha()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             //   FirebaseUser firebaseUser = autenticacaoFirebase.getCurrentUser();
                telaPrincipal();
            } else {
                String erroExcecao = "";
                try {
                    throw task.getException();
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                    erroExcecao = "E-mail inválido e/ou senha incorreta";
                    MetodosAuxiliares.Alert(LoginActivity.this, erroExcecao);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    MetodosAuxiliares.Alert(LoginActivity.this, "Verifique seu e-mail e/ou senha");
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na primeira linha do método `efetuarLogin()` adicione:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Titulo", "Texto", true);
```

Depois, dentro do seu `onComplete()` adicione:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Embora isso mostre um ProgressDialog, não acredito que haja uma forma de recuperar o atual progresso do sign in

Comment: Olá, ate funcionou, porém está depreciado. Mesmo assim obrigado.